# Calculate change of one variable based on relationship with other variable

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

If the volume scales V (km^3) with the area A (km^2) by a relationship V = 0.67*A^(1.262). Then how would the volume change if an area of 1161 km^2 decreases by 210.76 km^2?